# How to pass the manifest to player after processing?

Tags: chromecast, google-cast, google-cast-sdk

Once the manifest is obtained by using `host.processManifest` , necessary changes can be made. How can one pass the manifest to the player after this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your function needs to return the manifest as a string value.